# Define the color of different types in bidirectional bar chart

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply different colors for type "down" and type "up". How can I define the specific color the type for down (blue) and type up (red)? Thank you in advance for any advice!

The following is my data:

```
 category| number| type;
 a|-1|down; b|-4|down; a|30|up; b|22|up.
```

I tried to use `scale_fill_manual` in my example, but it seems to be used for all single direction bar charts in those examples I could find. I wonder how to use scale_fill_manual for bidirectional bar chart. Below is the code I used. I am fairly new to R. I appreciate any comments.

```
testData = read.csv("C:/Users/K/Desktop/example001.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = testData, 
       aes(x = category, y = number, 
       fill = factor(type))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "identity", stat = "identity", width = 0.5) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(title = "example001") + 
  ylim(-50, 50)
```

what I want is blue for downregulation and red for upregulation, not like the colors in the attched image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXGq9.png)

Comment: Hi, please provide reproducible data by editing your post to include the output of `dput(df))`, where `df` is your dataframe, or `dput(head(df, 20))` if your dataframe is quite large.

Comment: Something like `scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))`.

Comment: Thank you for both comments! I updated the question. It seems that scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red")) is used in all single directional bar chart. I wonder how to use it in the bidirectional bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

As @jon-spring suggested, simply add `scale_fill_manual` to your ggplot object:

```
+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","red"))
```

If you don't want to figure out the order, you can assign specific colours to specific factors:

```
+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("down"="blue","up"="red"))
```

You can even use hex codes for very specific colours:

```
+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("down"="#0433ff","up"="#ff2500"))
```